# I/O Analysis for External Merge Sort

Tags: cloud, mergesort

We are given 9 sorted arrays, each of size 100 MB. Our goal is to merge them using a 9-way merge sort on a machine with a RAM size of 100 MB with the following configuration and steps:
• 90 MB is allocated for input buffers.
• 10 MB is reserved for the output buffer.
• When processing the 9-way merging:
o Once the output buffer reaches its 10 MB capacity, transfer its contents to the final sorted file on the disk and clear the output buffer.
o If an input buffer is emptied during the merging, refill it with the next 10 MB from its associated 100 MB sorted chunk.
• Continue the process until all chunks are merged, resulting in a fully sorted 900 MB file.
(Calculate the total I/O (in MB) for this merge sort.)

i am trying the n merge sort algorithm to solve this question but with no answer,
i feel like i didnt understand the question
can someone explain it to me ?

Comment: Hints - the 9 input buffers are 10MB each. The code will be reading and writing 900 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Since the input files are already sorted, the process will just merge the 9 files in one pass, reading each file 10MB at a time and writing the merged file also 10MB at a time... So to total I/O bandwidth used is the combined lengths of all the input files and the length of the output file: 900MB read and 900MB written.

Handling the I/O is very easy: you can set the buffer size with `setvbuf` and leave the buffering to the stream handling functions.

Writing an optimal 9-way merge is more challenging.